# Password Manager

Tags: password-management, business-continuity

I work at a small business that needs a new password management software solution.

**Our needs are:**

Multiple Databases (one for IT passwords, one for Accounting passwords, etc...)

Multiple Users-about 8-10-(these users should also be under access control under one admin)
-I'll need to be able to grant access to only certain DBs per user.

Easy access to the database only within our Intranet.
-users should not be able to access these files outside of the company (other than through VPN)

The price should be either free or under $100 (for about 8-10 users)

**Other features that would be nice:**

User Logging (what gets added/when/and by who)

Active Directory

*I've searched everywhere for something to meet these needs and it's always in the thousands of dollars.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.*

Comment: I'm curious why do u need it :)

Comment: Very interested to see the answers to this one - we desperately need a solution for this but none of us have the time to research it.

Comment: @Tync - in our case, we have dozens of DMZ servers.  Being DMZ, they are not accessible using Domain Admin credentials, and each server has a unique local Administrator password.  Add into that hundreds of Cisco, wireless, etc devices and it's a headache trying to manage the collective Crapton of passwords

Comment: There is a similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/61402/web-based-and-encrypted-password-license-etc-database/61898#61898

Comment: There is a similar question pertaining to corporate password safes here: http://serverfault.com/questions/119892

Answer (score 4):

Check out [KeePass](http://keepass.info/)  it should handle your requirements, except for 'Active Directory, although I'm not sure what you mean by that.

[KeePass](http://keepass.info/)  has:

- **Strong Security**
- **Multiple User Keys**
- **Portable and No Installation Required**
- Export To TXT, HTML, XML and CSV Files
- Import From Many File Formats
- Easy Database Transfer
- **Support of Password Groups**
- Time Fields and Entry Attachments
- Auto-Type, Global Auto-Type Hot Key and Drag&Drop
- Intuitive and Secure Clipboard Handling
- Searching and Sorting
- Multi-Language Support
- Strong Random Password Generator
- Plugin Architecture
- **Open Source!**

Comment: +2 - I've been using this for many years and it's FREE!

Comment: Where do you see multiple user keys? http://keepass.info/help/base/multiuser.html says "All users use the same master password and/or key file to open the database."

Answer (score 1):

@Tync - Like Izzy said, password storage amongst a company is hell.  For IT we have multiple wifi/server accounts/old employee passwords/web site credentials/etc...

On top of that, Accounting also has dozens of passwords to websites that they'll never remember (And for security reasons shouldn't all be the same).

We may be going to go with Secret Server http://www.thycotic.com/products_secretserver_buynow.html

It's past our price range...but we really havent found anything else.

BTW...these needs are for a company of a whopping 18 employees, haha.

Answer (score 1):

There are a java based web solution named webkeepass for more information please see:
http://ossfree.net/webkeepass/

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Passwordstate](http://www.clickstudios.com.au/) from Click Studios.  It seems to meet your requirements and is free for less than 10 users.

Answer (score 0):

[Network Password Manager - enterprise password manager for Windows 2000/2003/XP/Vista networks](http://www.sowsoft.com/password-manager.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PasswordSafe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/), which is free. The multiple databases is no problem and you can use normal file/folder permissions to restrict access to each. It won't do the logging or integrate with AD though. One big plus, at least for me, is that there are Linux and Mac versions (the Mac version is unfortunately JAVA based), all of which happily work with the same database files.

It's also Open Source, so if it's close to what you want but not quite there you have the possibility of customizing it to suit.

Comment: While PasswordSafe is a good software, it is not "multi-user" by any stretch.

Answer (score 0):

We are the developers of Passwordstate and as DLux mentioned, we believe our product should meet your needs, and possibly at no cost.

If you have any questions at all, please visit our support page at our web site, where you'll be able to PM me - I'd be only to glad to help.

Web: [Click Studios](http://www.clickstudios.com.au)

Regards
Mark

Answer (score 0):

[Password Manager XP](http://www.cp-lab.com/index.html) despite its old school name is very capable and inexpensive. It handles multiple databases, access by different users and groups of users including AD authentication. The pro version has the user logging you are looking for.

We have been using it for a couple of years and have different access for our server team, applications and desktop support teams. It has been great and saved us from insecure excel spreadsheets and other dodgy ways of recording and sharing passwords.

As it also allows you to store files as attachments we use it to store SSL private keys, licence keys which are as important as passwords and often overlooked or neglected.